# Gmail api authorization

Tags: android

Initially with debug version the gmail api authorization was working properly. After I generated the signed apk of the app and applied proguard on the release apk the gmail api authorization checks authorization for some accounts while for some it does not check for the authorization. Why is this happening, is it because of applying proguard?

Comment: i think this is due to the security of google.

Comment: Hello, did you find the reason for this? I am facing the same problem